# <apex:inlineEditSupport> does not work for outputField in pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I am trying to make the "Quantity" field inline-editable

Here is my VF code:

```
<apex:page controller="CustomQuoteController" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Quote Generator" id="quotegen">
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="qliList" value="{!qliList}" var="qliProd" columns="3">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                    {!products[qliProd.Product2Id].Name}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!qliProd.Quantity}">
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
                    </apex:outputField>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!delQLI}" rerender="qliList" value="Remove">
                        <apex:param name="qliID" value="{!qliProd.Id}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The  tag doesn't seem to be doing anything. When I double click on the field in the pageBlockTable, nothing happens. It cannot be edited.

Comment: did you check your browsers console? any errors there?

Comment: @glls yes, I checked the console. No errors.

Comment: Note: I am using a custom controller class. I don't know if that has anything to do with it. Does inlineEditSupport only work on standard controllers or standard controller extension classes?

Comment: I also tried adding mode="inlineEdit" to the apex:pageBlock, but that didn't work either

Comment: @ag415 [How to correctly use apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit hideOnEdit attributes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10785/how-to-correctly-use-apexinlineeditsupport-showonedit-hideonedit-attributes)

Comment: @glls the example in the official salesforce documentation uses outputField: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm My issue also isn't to do with buttons. When I double click the field I don't get an editable box at all, nothing happens at all. It should change the output field to an editable text box on double click but does not

Comment: did you check the FLS to see if the field is set to readonly?

Comment: If I use inputField, it will always display as an editable box, but I want it to only display as editable when the field is double clicked. by default, I want it to display as a regular output field until the user double clicks on it

Comment: How about this, I can almost  guarantee you that Accessibility mode is enabled on the user record. that is messing up your javascript events

Comment: @Rao The field in question is the "Quantity" standard field on Quote Line Items. I went into "Field Accessiblity" to check it's settings. Strangely, I am seeing two different "Quantity" fields in the list, one is set to "Required" and the other is set to "Read-Only."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
OP did not enable inline edit in the user interface setting

Make sure "Enable Inline Editing" is checked in user interface.

Check if you have enabled Accessibility mode on the user record.

Inline edit and some other JS events may get messed up when Accessibility is turned on.

If it is not the accessibility mode check this doc to see what other factors can impact inline editing

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_inline_editing.htm

> Inline editing isn’t available in:
>
> **Accessibility mode**
>
> Setup pages
>
> Dashboards
>
> Customer Portal
>
> Descriptions for HTML solutions

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure we are not using accessibility mode, but I don't know how to confirm this. Would you happen to know how I can check if this is enabled? I tried searching "accessibility" in the setup but didn't see an option for that

Comment: Go to the user record and search for accessibility mode (classic only)

Comment: I just checked the user record, it says accessibility mode is disabled

Comment: I suspect the problem has to do with the field level security of the field. I am not sure why I am seeing two different "Quantity" fields under quote line items...

Comment: did you or your peers rename the a standard field in quote line item to Quantity ?

Comment: you are not using the VF page in customer portal are you ?

Comment: Update: looks like someone who worked on the system before me had created a read-only formula field labeled "Quantity" which is why I was seeing 2 "Quantity" fields in the list. However I am pretty sure I am using the original Quantity field which is not set to read-only. In my VF page I am referencing qliProd.Quantity, and the custom field they created has the API name QuantityF__c

Comment: and no I am not using the page in customer portal. It is a regular VF page in regular salesforce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68169/discussion-between-rao-and-ag415).